# How to access render_to_response context (data) in template as array object?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have below code in my view which is sending data to the template as follow -

```
@page_template("app/Discover.html") 
def Discover(request, template="app/Discover.html", extra_context=None):    
    context = {}
    context['to_loc']=loc_both
    context['to_av']=av_both
    context['to_ql']=ql_both    
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my template, I am able to access context items as below -

```
{% if to_loc %}
js_loc = {{ to_loc|safe }};       
{% endif %}
alert('Location is : '+JSON.stringify(js_loc,null,2));

{% if to_av %}
js_av = {{ to_av|safe }};       
{% endif %}
alert('AV is : '+JSON.stringify(js_av,null,2));
```

This way am able to access individual items from context. 
But, is there any way I can do something as below -

Assign context object to a javascript array object and this javascript array contains the list of context objects -> which I can access like below -

```
jsonList = [];
jsonList = contextJSON;  // contextJSON holds the context objects that are sent by my view above
print(JSON.stringify(jsonList.to_loc));  // this should give me the data of locations from respective context object
print(JSON.stringify(jsonList.to_av)); // this is for for AV
```

How to assign entire context object into my javascript object contextJSON in js file as array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put your context as JSON object into itself:

```
@page_template("app/Discover.html") 
def Discover(request, template="app/Discover.html", extra_context=None):    
     context = {}
     context['to_loc']=loc_both
     context['to_av']=av_both
     context['to_ql']=ql_both    
     if extra_context is not None:
         context.update(extra_context)
     ctx_copy = context.copy()
     context['context_json'] = simplejson.dumps(ctx_copy)
     return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And just render it into your template as JavaScript variable:

```
jsonList = [];
jsonList = {{ context_json|safe }};  // contextJSON holds the context objects that are sent by my view above
print(JSON.stringify(jsonList.to_loc));  // this should give me the data of locations from respective context object
print(JSON.stringify(jsonList.to_av)); // this is for for AV
```

Comment: So, tried with new object set and assigned context to it, but I cannot access it as an array in template. Also tried removing the json.dumps, Could you please check?

Comment: I added a `copy()` to the `context dict`. You need to use the json.dumps() to give the dict a json structure. What is the output of `{{ context_json }}` in your template?

Comment: I don't know if this is your complete context object. Just changed the package to `simplejson` and outsourced the copy to a new variable.

Comment: Hi @RodrigoDela, It was my mistake, I rectified it.. But the output of {{ context_json }} in template gives {&quot;to_loc&quot....;]} this way. I cannot access jsonList.to_loc now.. Could you please help?

Comment: I added |safe.. it now outputs '/' in between the data.. so, couldn't access jsonList.to_loc

Comment: Could your paste the context json content somewhere? Pastebin or smth?

Comment: I have identified the issue, it was due to one object containing None field.. It works fine now.. Thanks a lot for your help!